# Inverted Half Triangle using Astrix Problem

Tags: c++

Hi I'm trying to get my C++ console to output the first image I've attached. I know you have to like count the spaces in like maybe a for loop and decrement it as you go down the rows..However, I'm not exactly sure on how to go about that, pretty new to c++. The solution I'm currently working on is the exact mirror image of it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
int rows = 10;
    for (int i = 0; i <= rows; i++) {
        cout << "" << endl;

        for (int j = 1; j <= i; ++j) {
            cout << "*";
        } 

    } 
}
```

Correct Solution:  [image: 1]

My Current Output:  [image: 2]

Comment: "count the spaces" Yes. Do so. How many spaces do you count in the first desired output row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an extra `for` loop before the one that is sending the asterisks, like so that will send the spaces to push the asterisks to the right.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    int rows = 10;
    for (int i = 0; i <= rows; i++) {
        for (int j = rows - i; j > 0; j--) {
          cout << " ";
        }
        for (int j = 1; j <= i; ++j) {
            cout << "*";
        } 
        cout << endl;
    } 
}
```

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    int rows = 10;
    for (int i = 0; i <= rows; i++) {
        cout << "" << endl; // Mistake here, you are putting a empty string

        for (int j = 1; j <= i; ++j) {
            cout << "*";
        } 

    } 
}
```

You're almost good. You have missed to put the spaces in order to create the *right padding* of the stars.